# Stack overflow issue with array of linkedlist

Tags: c++

For starters my program is to create a hash table of names where collison is handled by chaining.
So i create an array of Linked List. Problem is my array is very large 88801 to be exact.  Im thinking thats why im getting a stack over flow but im not sure.  My code is below.  Some one tried telling me to make the array a set of pointers to linked list.
IE putting LinkedList* hashbucket1[88801] which this removed the stack overflow issue but caused other linking errors.  Guess im trying to figure out what is the best way to impliment an array of linked list of strings.  If im on the right track and its something small im over looking please point it out or tell me to scrap this and start over with a given path in mind.  If i need to link or zip up my other files let me know and i can.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

 unsigned long djb2(string& str) 
 { 
 unsigned long hash = 5381; 

  for(string::iterator it = str.begin();it!=str.end();it++)  
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *it; /* hash * 33 + character */ 

 return hash; 
 }

  static unsigned long sdbm(string& str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    int c;

   for(string::iterator it = str.begin();it!=str.end();it++)
        hash = *it + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;

    return hash;
  }


  void insert(LinkedList HashList1[], LinkedList HashList2[], int listSize);

    int main() {
char command;
int listSize = 88801;
LinkedList HashList1[88801];
LinkedList HashList2[88801];
bool invalidcommand;
do{
    do{
        cout << "MENU" << endl;
        cout << "(I)nsert new entry" << endl;
        cout << "(S)earch" << endl;
        cout << "(D)elete Entry" << endl;
        cout << "(C)reate Hast Table" << endl;
        cout << "(L)og File" << endl;
        cout << "(Q)uit and Exit Program" << endl;

        cin >> command;

    if(command == 'I'){
        insert(HashList1, HashList2, listSize);
    }else if(command == 'S'){
  //            search(HashList1, HashList2, listSize);
    }else if(command == 'D'){

    }else if(command == 'L'){ 
    //  save(HashList1, HashList2, listSize);
    }else if(command == 'C'){
    //  load(HashList1, HashList2, listSize);
    }
}while(command != 'Q');

return 0;
    };

    void insert(LinkedList HashList1[], LinkedList HashList2[], int listSize){

string lastName;
bool invalidID;
//Person newPerson;
do
{
    invalidID = false;
    cout << "Please enter Last Name: ";
    cin >> lastName;
    while(cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }
}while(invalidID);
//newPerson.setLastName(lastName);
int hashBucket1;
int hashBucket2;
hashBucket1 = djb2(lastName) % listSize;
hashBucket2 = sdbm(lastName) % listSize;
LinkedList bucket1;
if(!HashList1[hashBucket1].find(lastName)){     
    //HashList1[hashBucket1].insert(newPerson);
    HashList1[hashBucket1].insert(lastName);

}else{
    if(!bucket1.find(lastName)){

        HashList1[hashBucket1].insert(lastName);
    }else{
    cout << "List already contains an entry with the last name " << lastName << endl;
    }
}
LinkedList bucket2;
if(HashList2[hashBucket2].find(lastName)){
//  bucket2.insert(newPerson);
}else{
    if(!bucket2.find(lastName)){
        //bucket2.insert(newPerson);
    }else{
    cout << "List already contains an entry with the last name " << lastName << endl;
    }
}
   }
```

Comment: Accept some answers on questions you've already asked; [see the FAQ on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem, as you correctly suspect, is that you are running out of stack space. You shouldn't be placing such big objects on the stack, which is a limited and precious resource. Instead, you can use pointers and allocate them dynamically on the heap.

The problematic code is here:

```
int main() {
char command;
int listSize = 88801;
LinkedList HashList1[88801]; // << this
LinkedList HashList2[88801]; // << and this
```

also note that `LinkedList* hashbucket1[88801]` is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. What you want is:

```
LinkedList (*HashList1)[88801]
```

or, with `typedef` to make it more readable:

```
typedef LinkedList LinkedListArray[88801];
LinkedListArray* HashList1;
```

but by then it would be better to just do:

```
LinkedList *HashList1 = new LinkedList[88801];
```

Comment: Thank you figured that was the reason. How would it look as a parameter I tried replacing my insert function with                void insert(LinkedList (*HashList1[]), LinkedList (*HashList2[]), int listSize);  but it says the arguments and parameters dont match. and just to make sure i understand it correct           LinkedList (*HashList1)[88801];                                     is a pointer to an array but is it an array of pointers also? because when i insert something into this array it needs to be a linked list to take care of chaining for collison in the hash function

Comment: @Jeremy: It would be easier if you go with the latest alternative, and use it just like a regular pointer. If you are using `LinkedList (*HashList1)[88801]` for declaring your type, then as a function parameter you could write `LinkedList (*HashList1)[88801]` or `LinkedList (*HashList1)[]`, due to array decay the actually mean the same there.

Comment: @Jeremy: `LinkedList (*HashList1)[88801]` is a pointer to an array of `LinkedList`, is not a pointer to an array of pointers to `LinkedList`. Each element of the array is of type `LinkedList`, that should work for you right?